# Assemble a date and time concatenation that can be read by an hour and minute difference equation

Tags: excel

4/27/2009 is in a cell with a Date format.  It says "4/27/2009" (w/out the quotes of course).

In another cell I've got "2:30 PM" (again, w/out the quotes).  Its underlying function is `=TIME(HOUR(P6),Q6,0)` where the hour is HOUR(P6) where P6 is a Custom format `m AM/PM`, and the minute is taken off a number formatted Q6, and I'm not concerned with secs., and the cell it resides in is formatted as Custom `h:mm AM/PM`.

Now how do I put them together in a third cell as "4/27/2009 2:30 PM" (w/out quotes of course) so that I can take a similarly constructed second value and be able to subtract one from the other and get a number of hours (nevermind minutes but I'll take those too)?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a formula in the third cell that adds the date cell and time cell should work. (`A3=A1+A2`). To calculate the difference you can use a subtraction (unsure) or a combination of `TIME` and [the `DATEDIF` function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx).

Comment: That's incredible.  How did you do that?

Comment: "Calculate the difference between two times" in Help has some good diff. stuff.  Thanks again, assylias.

Comment: "Not sure what you are referring to!"  It was humor (that the answer turned out to be a simple add using a +).  You saved me a lot of time.